# Example words with ɛ: + difference between ɛ: and ɛ

Tags: phonology, phonetics

I've just started studying phonetics and phonology of English and I'm currently trying to find words with the vowel ɛ: as examples for a homework. Also, is there a difference between ɛ: and ɛ, as in, does the "colon" make a difference? Because in my textbook I can only find this symbol without the "colon"

Comment: Welcome to ELU! Where have you tried looking? I think Wikipedia has a phonetics chart you could search.

Comment: @marcellothearcane I've spent solid 2 hours looking all over the internet and can't find anything :( I just don't understand the ɛː vowel.

Comment: No problem! We're here to help. If you do come across anything, please edit it in to the question.

Comment: @marcellothearcane so could you please help me with this?

Comment: I don't know either I'm afraid. There's definitely people around who would know.

Comment: The "colon" is the "long" symbol. The difference between ɛ: and ɛ is the difference between [*shared*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shared) and [*shed*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shed) — in many current U.K. dialects, this is mainly a difference in the length of the vowel.

Comment: Googling [**ipa vowel colon**](https://www.google.com/search?q=ipa+vowel+colon&oq=ipa+vowel+colon&aqs=chrome..69i57.5237j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), I find *The **triangular colon** or IPA long-vowel mark is a symbol that in small fonts **looks like a colon** and indicates a vowel that is longer than others,* without even leaving the Google home page.

Comment: @Peter: For some (mostly US rather than UK), the /r/ might be a relevant element there. But I don't think anything like that would apply *He **weed** his pants* and *He smokes **weed***. Where see no obvious reason why the percentage of people who'd enunciate those two detectably differently should be any different on either side of the pond (though I'm pretty sure in terms of likely *vocabulary* choices, the verb is more BrE and the noun more AmE! :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers!

Comment: I don't know what IPA symbol your textbook uses for the phoneme in *share*, but in IPA for American English, it's usually represented by /ɛr/ or /er/, and in 20th century British English, it's represented by /ɛə/ or maybe /eə/.

Comment: Where were you advised to search? This [YouTube Phonetic Chart British Male Voice Pronunciation Guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SwUpGllGvhw) _may_ help, but there already appear to be slight differences in analysis and labelling. You need to ask your teacher/tutor for their recommended resources.

Comment: And none of [these charts for US pronunciation](https://www.google.com/search?q=phonetic+chart+US&rlz=1C1ASRM_enGB617GB618&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=2839ylz0Yi4Z3M%253A%252C5zrqzLYhViTs8M%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kT_AMhLk56Jnoe_OW2Zs2BwbpNcFA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJmZOP7Y_mAhV4UBUIHfYOBLQQ9QEwAHoECAUQHA#imgrc=2839ylz0Yi4Z3M:) seem to mention ɛ or ɛ: either. Are you sure you've got the symbols right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a homework question, that does not fit the scope of the site.

Answer (score 2):

The vowel sound in English words such as "bed" and "dress" is usually denoted ɛ, not e.[1] You might get [ɛ:] in a non-rhotic accent where "air" is pronounced not as a diphthong but as the same [ɛ] vowel, lengthened. In such an accent, "shed" and "shared" would be pronounced exactly the same except for the length of the vowel.

[1]  However, this phoneme is pronounced differently in different accents, and [e] might be a fair representation of it in some accents where it is pronounced higher, e.g. New Zealand English.

Comment: Is it just me, or does BrE 'bed' have a (much) shorter vowel length than in AmE?

Answer (score 1):

**examples?**
I looked a bit in the [Oxford English Dictionary](https://oed.com) (subscription requuired).  There is this pronunciation:

**hair** Brit.  /hɛː/,  U.S. /hɛ(ə)r/

In the non-rhotic British pronunciation, the sound /ɛ/ is lengthened to /ɛː/ as the only result of the letter R in there.

Answer (score -3):

An IPA phonetic chart for British Received Pronunciation is shown below.  This may help answer your question.  It doesn't show both of your symbols — only one.

[image: RP vocalic phonemes]

Comment: I actually don't see *either* of the OP's symbols in that table . . .